# Animation rotate is diiferent from operation in Blender

Tags: armature

I'm modeling the machine which has crosshead, piston, piston rod and crankshaft.
I followed the [youtube tutorial](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=hQrimx91y7k&t=267s) to make animation for these parts.

Some objects were parented to one empty object like a piston in tutorial. The armature were added with bones:

- Scratch bone
- Piston bone
- Rod bone
- Crankshaft bone
- Crankshaft controller bone

[image]
[image]

The crankshaft controller bone could be rotated round Y axis in Blender during modeling.
Crankshaft, rod and piston animated well.

However, the crankshaft rotation became abnormal when added key frames: first key frame was set at 1 frame with Z rotation 0 value; last key frame was set at 60 frame with Z rotation 360 value.
[image]
[image]

The abnormal offset was found during the animation was played. The crankshaft was rotated with axis offset. The offset could not be found when selecting controller bone then press R and press Y, then moving the mouse arrow in blender.
[image]

Could you please help to fix the problem? It seems the rotations are hard to master in Blender.

The original blender file can be found at Google Drive. https://drive.google.com/file/d/1IJA6VThYaxLCrik5f0GzDvcy_AW2wbFn/view?usp=sharing

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The logic behind your rig is correct, and it should work fine.

The Reason of the error is a lack of precision in the modelling stage: in my example the object named SOLID.006 should be centered on the same X and Z coordinates along its Y axis but it isn't: I've put three empties centered in 3 different edge loops, and in the 2nd image it's shown that they are misaligned.

The problem is present even without keyframing, when pressing R, Y to rotate the rod.004 bone manually.

[image]

[image]

Comment: Thank you. You're right. The model precision is terrible. It's downloaded from Internet. I'm going to modeling new one by myself.